# How can I find all unused methods of my project in the Android Studio IDE?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

How can I find all **unused methods and variables** of my project in the **Android Studio IDE**?

Comment: Mr. DownVoter, may I ask you why you down vote this question?

Comment: Not my downvote, but maybe it was someone who read the first words of the title and thought your question falls in an off-topic category: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." I don't think your question is off-topic, but you might want to change the title to "How can I find..." as you wrote in the question body, to prevent misunderstandings.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In the android studio(or more generally in the Intellij IDEA) you can specify inspection code that you want to analyze from **`Analyze->Inspect Code...`** and then define the scope of your code.
You can see the result for my code in the below picture:

[image]

In **`Declaration redundancy`** you can see that "someMethod" is declared unused. Also, in **`Probable bugs`** you can find variable **`i`** is never used.

Comment: And an easy way to get the job done. Thanks to both of you guys.

Comment: Why is this setting not sticky?  Every time I open Android Studio I have to recheck this setting.  And I always explicitly Apply and press Ok.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays its in Analyze->Inspect Code... and then you need to go to Kotlin | Redundant contructs | Unused symbol

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also install the `QAPlug via File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories -> QAPlug`.

For Mac:

```
Android Studio -> Preferences... -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories -> QAPlug.
```

In QAPlug is PMD, FindBugs, Checkstyle and Hammurapi integrated.
These tools are very nice to find dead code, bugs, increase performance and make the code more readable.
I highly recommend those tools if you work for a bigger project.

Comment: How to use this plugin

Comment: How will it tell bugs to developers can you explain a bit more

Comment: Android 3.0, installed pluging, keeps crashing on AS restart or if I try to use it... Anyone got it working with AS 3.0?