# Remove all unused classes,methods from Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have used the lint(**Analyze->Inspect** Code...) and find out unused methods and resources. All the unused resources removed by **Refractor->Remove unused Resources** but not found any option like this to remove java classes and methods. 
Is there any feature in the android studio or any Plugin which can remove all the java classes, the methods which are not used in code to save manual refracting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all unused methods of my project in the Android Studio IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674592/how-can-i-find-all-unused-methods-of-my-project-in-the-android-studio-idea)

Comment: @Nirekin My question is to "Remove Unused classes and methods" not "find unused methods"

Comment: I believe it is not automated. you have to do it by hands

Answer (score 79):

This can be achieved by using the built-in inspection `Java | Declaration redundancy | Unused declaration`.

To run it on whole project go to `Code -> Analyze -> Run inspection by name...`, type `Unused declaration` and select desired scope.
Then carefully check output and mark some classes as entry points if needed.

Now you can select `Unused declaration` node in list and perform `Safe delete` action on all unused declarations at once.

[image: Inspection result]

For Kotlin there is similar inspection `Kotlin | Redundant constructs | Unused symbol`.

Comment: Hi, I can not see Kotlin | Redundant constructs | Unused symbol option.
Could you help

Comment: @MrMike inspections in `Analyze -> Run inspection by name...` can't be found by full names, you can try just `Unused symbol`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwTwx.png

Answer (score 8):

Android ships with ProGuard and can do what you want. If you are using Gradle as build system then you can add the following lines in your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {

    // ... other configurations

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Your `proguard-rules-debug.pro` file only needs to contain one line

```
-dontobfuscate
```

With this additions your release build will get shrunk and obfuscated, your debug build, however, will get only shrunk, i.e, unnecessary code is removed.
 Note, that ProGuard operates on the build and not the source code.

The [ProGuard FAQ](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#shrinking) has some more information of what it can do.

Comment: I believe topic starter is bothered with Android Studio findings and not about cleaning apk from unused methods

Comment: @EugenMartynov Maybe, but it is not clearly stated in the question. Maybe OP can shed some light on it.

Comment: You are telling the solution for removing unused methods at runtime. Need to remove the unused methods while developing.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1

Generate usage.txt and mapping.txt with Proguard or R8

- Add `-printusage` to your proguard.pro file Run
- `./gradlew app:minifyReleaseWithProguard` or `./gradlew app:minifyReleaseWithR8`

Step 2

Find class name records that is in usage.txt but **not** in mapping.txt, those are the unused classes that are removed by Proguard/ R8
It's not hard to write such algorithm but you can consider using HashTable or Binary Tree.

I've elaborated more [here](https://ericntd.medium.com/find-unused-classes-in-android-codebase-c3c9fc686f4b)